# Newer version of R does not load older packages

Tags: r, vim, package, vim-plugin

I have some issues with regard to package `VIMGUI`. As I am trying to use it, the warning comes like this:

```
Loading required package: data.table
Error in load Namespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘stringi’
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘VIM’ was built under R version 3.1.2 
2: package ‘data.table’ was built under R version 3.1.1 
Error: package ‘data.table’ could not be loaded
```

When I try to install `data.table` the error comes like this:

```
package ‘data.table’ is not available (for R version 3.1.0)
```

Comment: run `update.packages()`.

Comment: I have almost all packages updated

Comment: Since you are likely not using a personal library for packages, *after you update R*, you can either move all packages over to the new *R* directory and do `update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE)` or perhaps try [this suggestion](http://www.schulte-mecklenbeck.com/2011/04/resinstalling-packages-in-r-after-update/).

Comment: What do you mean by "almost all packages updated"? What version of *R* is installed? What is your OS? Perhaps you could edit your question and include the output from `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Yeah, you say your errors are saying "for R version 3.1.0", suggesting that you're running a year-old version of R. 3.2.0 was released a couple weeks ago.

Comment: I am using R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) -- "Spring Dance"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing

Comment: After clicking update, it says you are using newest version of R

Comment: You likely (still) need to run `update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE)` as I suggested earlier, especially after updating *R*. After that, you can try to install the packages again (no harm is done by installing again). After all of that, if you are still having problems, you need to provide [more information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

If you are being told that R 3.1.0 is up-to-date then you are using a mirror that is a year behind the current version, which you've already been advised is 3.2.0. Furthermore the current version of pkg:data.table is 1.9.5 from github and it says it only requires "R >= 2.14.0" so why a mirror would give you that error is a complete mystery. Updates of R within minor versions (from 3.1.0 to 3.1.2 or 3.1.3 for instance) are generally painless and let you avoid the gentle warnings (notice: *not* an error) such as you see such as "package ‘VIM’ was built under R version 3.1.2".

I'm also not seeing why `data.table` would need VIM or stringi for that matter. Those packages are not in either the Improts or the Depends listing for 'data.table'. So I'm guessing there is a bunch of other code you have not provided that made the failed attempt at loading the `data.table`-package.

Update to 3.1.3 (obtained from a more complete CRAN mirror than you appear to be using.) Then post the output of `sessionInfo()` and maybe the output of

```
(mypacks <- installed.packages()[ , 1:3])
```

That would tell you what versions are currently in your library and whether you have multiple libraries. I wouldn't want to post that because for me

```
 > nrow(mypacks)
 [1] 1333
```

But for someone with only a few packages installed, it will give you a complete listing of your current versions and where they are on your drives. You could also post:

```
mypacks[ mypacks[, 'Package']  %in% c('data.table', 'stringi', 'VIM') , ]
### Output from my setup:
           Package     
data.table "data.table"
stringi    "stringi"   
VIM        "VIM"       
           LibPath                                                         
data.table "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library"
stringi    "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library"
VIM        "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library"
           Version
data.table "1.9.5"
stringi    "0.4-1"
VIM        "4.0.0"
```

Comment: Thank you All..i was actually updating throughout year only RStudio and not R......It sometimes confuses that R and R Studio is same....but i hope now sorted the issue was able to run VIMGUI....I copied all pakages from 3.1.0 folder and pasted in 3.2.0......Although packages are working well but some show errors....did i do right